# Background Worker Check For When It's Midnight?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I want to create a background worker for a WinForm that triggers code whenever midnight rolls by.

I have an idea of how to do it, but I'm pretty sure it's not the best way to do it.

```
while(1==1)
{
//if Datetime.Now == midnight, execute code
//sleep(1second)
}
```

Comment: Quick note... If you ever want to create an "endless" loop like that (which could have a `break`, of course), you can do `while (true) { }`.  `1==1` evaluates to `true` anyway.

Comment: Is that the accepted standard?  I never was sure about the ok-ness of using 1==1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a `System.Timers.Timer` and at application start up just calculate the difference between `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.Today.AddDays(0)`. Then set the interval for that amount.

I actually did something just like this recently:

```
public static class DayChangedNotifier
{
    private static Timer timer;

    static DayChangedNotifier()
    {
        timer = new Timer(GetSleepTime());
        timer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
            {
                OnDayChanged(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
                timer.Interval = this.GetSleepTime();
            };
        timer.Start();

        SystemEvents.TimeChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_TimeChanged);
    }

    private static void SystemEvents_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Interval = GetSleepTime();
    }

    private static double GetSleepTime()
    {
        var midnightTonight = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
        var differenceInMilliseconds = (midnightTonight - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        return differenceInMilliseconds;
    }

    private static void OnDayChanged(DayOfWeek day)
    {
        var handler = DayChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(null, new DayChangedEventArgs(day));
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler<DayChangedEventArgs> DayChanged;
}
```

AND:

```
public class DayChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DayChangedEventArgs(DayOfWeek day)
    {
        this.DayOfWeek = day;
    }

    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; private set; }
}
```

Usage: `DayChangedNotifier.DayChanged += ....`

Comment: @Soo: Nope.  The Timer won't block (stopping the rest of your code -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_%28computing%29).  Once the interval is up, it will call the `Tick` event.  At that point you can stop the timer if you wish, calculate the next interval and start it up again.

Comment: No, the System.Timers fires on another thread so all you need to be careful about is to call Invoke in your event handler of the timer.

Comment: Or use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead, this one fires the Tick() event in the Form's thread.

Comment: There is one giant caveat in this solution, that is when you run your application as a (windows) service, then you need an extra helper class to get the system time changed event.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0  Use a helper class like this: public class ServiceSystemEvents : IServiceSystemEvents, IDisposable

Answer (score 7):

Instead you could user a Timer and set the timer tick interval to be the time between Now() and midnight.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why polling solutions were voted up when Microsoft solved this type of problem years ago by adding a windows service to handle timing.  Just create a scheduled task to run the exe.  No extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) to schedule that. Maybe is like a  cannon to kill a mosquito in this scenario, but that's is the only scheduling job framework i know and works excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use polling. Instead, set up a timer task, set it to fire at midnight, and add an event to process.

```
 TimeSpan timeBetween = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now;

 System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
 t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);
 t.Interval = 1000 * timeBetween.Seconds;
 t.Start();
```

Comment: So after t_Elapsed is triggered, is timeBetween recalculated?

Comment: You would recalculate the interval in the t_Elapsed method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confuse about why you need a WinForm, will it be running at midnight?  If all you need is some sort process to run, use the windows scheduler to run it at midnight.  (On XP, but I believe Win server should be similar)Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks -> Add Scheduled Task -> Fill out the wizard.  Save you a lot of coding.