# Event for DateChange at midnight

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Background Worker Check For When It's Midnight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053695/background-worker-check-for-when-its-midnight)

Is there a SystemEvent which I can register to and which will be published at midnight, when the Date has changed?

Comment: The Windows Task Scheduler would suit you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a class I use to handle this. It's similar to @sll's answer, however takes into account the system time changing and also will trigger each midnight instead of only once.

```
static class MidnightNotifier
{
    private static readonly Timer timer;

    static MidnightNotifier()
    {
        timer = new Timer(GetSleepTime());
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
        {
            OnDayChanged();
            timer.Interval = GetSleepTime();
        };
        timer.Start();

        SystemEvents.TimeChanged += OnSystemTimeChanged;
    }

    private static double GetSleepTime()
    {
        var midnightTonight = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
        var differenceInMilliseconds = (midnightTonight - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        return differenceInMilliseconds;
    }

    private static void OnDayChanged()
    {
        var handler = DayChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(null, null);
    }

    private static void OnSystemTimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Interval = GetSleepTime();
    }

    public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> DayChanged;
}
```

Since it's a static class, you can subscribe to the event using code like:

```
MidnightNotifier.DayChanged += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine("It's midnight!"); };
```

Comment: Doesn't take into account the system time changing and won't trigger after the "first" midnight (although not clear whether the questioner wants that).

Comment: +1 Right, `SystemEvents.TimeChanged` is a good catch!

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Task Scheduler is generally the proper way to start something at a specified date.

But if you are really searching for an event or equivalent:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer((DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) – DateTime.Now).
    TotalMillisecond);
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnMidnight);
timer.Start();
```

Comment: This won't work since timer will raise Elapsed event almost each second

Comment: @sll: How's that? `(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) – DateTime.Now).Millisecond)` is the number of ms until midnight.

Comment: No, Milliseconds would return a value of milliseconds of a timespan, you need `TotalMilliseconds` value instead. You can check it - give it a try