# c# detect when day changes

Tags: c#, wpf

In my app I've a ticker which runs every 5 seconds. I've also an internal clock and I want to detect when the day chages. 
To test, I have tried the following code without success:

```
DateTime A = new DateTime(2019, 6, 20, 23, 58, 29);       
DateTime B = new DateTime(2019, 6, 21, 00, 01, 12);
Int32 dd = (B-A).Days;          // it returns 0
double dd = (B-A).TotalDays;    // it return 0.00002136213
```

If I check if **TotalDays > 0** I succesfully detect the day change but in the follwing case (with a difference of a minute)

```
DateTime C = new DateTime(2019, 6, 20, 12, 58, 29);
DateTime D = new DateTime(2019, 6, 20, 12, 59, 29);
```

the compare fails. Since I need to call a method when day changes, with the example above its called every time and I do not want this behevior. Any hint?

Comment: What do you mean, do you want to know when twenty four hours has passed or simply when the application has been running for a day, then change the value?

Comment: The result is correct. You possibly wants to set time of both dates to 00:00:00 and then subtract. Try (B.Date - A.Date).Days

Comment: Your answer is  here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480063/event-for-datechange-at-midnight?lq=1)

Comment: @AnilGoel I think yours is the best solution, thanks

Answer (score 5):

compare `Date` part of DateTime directly

```
bool isSameDay = (A.Date == B.Date);
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at only the Date parts

```
DateTime A = new DateTime(2019, 6, 20, 23, 58, 29);       
DateTime B = new DateTime(2019, 6, 21, 00, 01, 12);
Int32 dd = (B.Date-A.Date).Days;
```

Answer (score 2):

For your ticker why not use TimeSpan variables to complete your comparison.  You set 1 static timespan variable to 24 hours (1 day) and then create a secondary one to store the values.  You then set your second timespan variable equal to the subtraction of your two days and this would let you know if a day had gone by.

`

```
TimeSpan newDayReference = new TimeSpan(24,0,0);
TimeSpan comparison;

//These two variables set to show difference.
DateTime A= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
DateTime B = DateTime.Now;
comparison = B - A;

if(comparison > newDayReference){ //success }
```

`